# Animation - growing shrinking image scale

Tags: iphone, image, animation, uiimageview, scaling

This seems like it should be easy enough, but I'm not able to figure out out tonight and have been searching but not finding anything relevant on the forums.

All I want to do is change the scale of a UIImageView to shrink it or grow it.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

image.whatDoIDoToMakeItGrowOrShrink?=)

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f); // shrink to half.
```

Comment: awesome! helped me too :) Thanks for both the question & the answer!